# Google Analytics api add-on times out

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, google-analytics-api, google-sheets-api

When I run the Google Sheets (Google Analytics Add-on) the reports run fine, however, when the automated hourly runs are done I get an hourly email that the reports "timed out" as seen below.

Error message
Service timed out: Spreadsheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spreadsheet service seems down, I have same issue on some apps that use Spreadsheet service. Still see nothing on https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard

I don't understand the comment I see ('And your programming question is?'). I understood this place is to help..

Comment: I have created issue on GAS issue tracker : https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4824